# How do I remove the null value in the selectbox array when nothing is selected

Tags: laravel, select

I am trying to validate an array of select option to check if it is empty as seen below. When  value is not selected the default value of the array is null which passes the validation. How do I remove the null value from the select box when nothing is selected or if there is any other way you can suggest.

My code

```
<select name="test_id[]" class="form-control select-test-{{$idselect}}"
       id="select-{{Illuminate\Support\Str::random(10)}}">
    <option value="">Select Patient Test</option>
    @foreach ($tests as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Laravel validation code

```
$request->validate([
    'test_id' => 'required:array'
], [
    'test_id.required' => "Test is required"
]);
```

it goes through even when no selected

Output when not selected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you give a value for an option it will be passed as a parameter, can you change this line:

`<option value="">Select Patient Test</option>`

As:

`<option disabled selected>Select Patient Test</option>`